# Does strong duality hold for this semidefinite program?

Tags: convex-optimization, duality, semidefinite-programming

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}$Consider the following semidefinite program (SDP)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_V \quad & \Tr(V) \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \sqrt{\lambda}AVC^T \\ \sqrt{\lambda}CVA^T & CVC^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
\quad & V \succeq 0
\end{aligned} \tag{1}
$$
where $V \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}, A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}, C \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}, Q \in \mathbb R^{n \times n} \succeq 0, R \in \mathbb R^{m \times m} \succ 0,$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. This SDP shows up in Theorem 6 in the paper

> B. Sinopoli, L. Schenato, M. Franceschetti, K. Poolla, M. I. Jordan, and S. S. Sastry, “Kalman filtering with intermittent observations,” IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control, vol. 49, no. 9, pp. 1453–1464, Sep. 2004, doi: 10.1109/TAC.2004.834121.

Suppose that the input parameters $A,C,Q,R,$ and $\lambda$ are always chosen such that a solution for $(1)$ exists. Does strong duality hold for $(1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}$It turns out that strong duality holds for a slightly different but equivalent SDP. We prove this using the following three steps:

1. We show that a matrix $V$ solves $(1)$ if and only if $V \succeq 0$ and it solves the following "modified" algebraic Riccati equation
   $$
   \begin{align}
   V &= AVA^T + Q - \lambda AVC^T (CVC^T + R)^{-1}CVA^T \\
   &= g_\lambda(V) \tag{2}
   \end{align}
   $$
   where we have defined the function
   $$
   g_\lambda(V) = AVA^T + Q - \lambda AVC^T (CVC^T + R)^{-1}CVA^T
   $$
   as given in equation (16) in the paper.
2. We show that a matrix $V \succeq 0$ solves $(2)$ if and only if the same matrix $V$ solves the problem
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \min_V \quad & \Tr(V) \\
   \textrm{s.t.} \quad & \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \sqrt{\lambda}AVC^T \\ \sqrt{\lambda}CVA^T & CVC^T + R \end{bmatrix} \preceq 0 \\
   \quad & V \succeq 0
   \end{aligned} \tag{3}
   $$
3. We invoke Slater's condition to show that that there exists a $V$ that is strictly feasible for the problem in $(3)$, which implies that strong duality holds for $(3)$.

Note that there is a typo in Theorem 6 in the paper, where the condition
$$
\begin{bmatrix} AVA^T - V & \sqrt{\lambda}AVC^T \\ \sqrt{\lambda}CVA^T & CVC^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
$$
should instead be
$$
\begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \sqrt{\lambda}AVC^T \\ \sqrt{\lambda}CVA^T & CVC^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
$$

### Step 1

Although a proof of the statement given in step 1 is given in part (b) of Theorem 6 in the paper, we repeat it here with some additional commentary for convenience (and to avoid repetition in step 2).

First, we show that if $V$ solves $(1)$, then $V$ solves $(2)$. Suppose that $V$ solves $(1)$ and suppose that, for the sake of contradiction, $V$ does not solve $(2)$.

Because $V$ is feasible in $(1)$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \sqrt{\lambda}AVC^T \\ \sqrt{\lambda}CVA^T & CVC^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
$$
Then, using the Schur complement lemma, $V \preceq g_\lambda(V)$. Next, because $V$ does not solve $(2)$, then $V \neq g_\lambda(V)$.

Because $V \preceq g_\lambda(V)$ and $V \neq g_\lambda(V)$, then $V \prec g_\lambda(V)$. This implies that $\Tr(V) \prec \Tr(g_\lambda(V))$. However, because $V$ solves $(1)$, such that for every $\tilde V$ in the feasible set of $(1)$, we have that $\Tr(V) \succeq \Tr(\tilde V)$, then there is a contradiction. Therefore, $V$ solves $(2)$.

Next, we show that if $V$ solves $(2)$, then $V$ solves $(1)$. Suppose that $V$ solves $(2)$, such that $V = g_\lambda(V)$. This implies that $V \preceq g_\lambda(V)$. By the Schur complement lemma, this implies that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \sqrt{\lambda}AVC^T \\ \sqrt{\lambda}CVA^T & CVC^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
$$
Hence, $V$ is feasible in $(1)$. It remains to show that $V$ is also maximal, in the sense that $\forall \tilde V \succeq 0, V \succeq \tilde V$. In corollary 13.1.2 in the book

> P. Lancaster and L. Rodman, Algebraic Riccati equations. in Oxford science publications. Oxford : New York: Clarendon Press ; Oxford University Press, 1995.

it was shown that, if the pair $(C,A)$ is detectable, then there exists a unique maximal solution to $(2)$. We will make this assumption to conclude that $V$ is maximal, and hence solves $(1)$.

### Step 2

We can employ a proof similar to the one given in step 1 to complete step 2. We omit this proof for brevity.

### Step 3

We now invoke [Slater's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_condition) to conclude that strong duality holds for $(3)$. First, suppose that $(A,Q)$ is controllable and $(C,A)$ is detectable, and let $\lambda > \overline{\lambda}$ as given in Theorem 6 in the paper by Sinopoli et al. given in the question.

Then, from theorem 5 (corollary 1) in the paper, there exists a $Z$ and $0 \prec Y \preceq I$ such that $\Psi_\lambda(Y,Z) \succ 0$. Next, from theorem 5 in the paper, because there exists a $Z$ and $0 \prec Y \preceq I$ such that $\Psi_\lambda(Y,Z) \succ 0$, then there exists an $X$ such that $X \succ g_\lambda(X)$.

Finally, from lemma 1(g) in Appendix A in the paper, because $X \succ g_\lambda(X)$, then $X \succ 0$. Note that the condition $X \succ 0$ is the strict version of the second constraint in $(3)$, and the condition $X \succ g_\lambda(X)$ is the strict version of the first constraint in $(3)$. Therefore, by Slater's condition, strong duality holds for $(3)$.